# How to change UI language of Marble for Windows?

Tags: windows-8, language

How to change UI language of [Marble](http://marble.kde.org/index.php) for Windows? I want to set it to English. Please don't send me to the documentation, which [say that `Help` menu should contain `Switch Application Language` item](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdeedu/marble/commands.html#idp7550384), because mine does not contain it:

[image]

Items there are saying, from top to bottom: (1) marble manual, (2) what is this, (3) about marble globe, (3) about qt. I.e. no any "switch app language".

So, I want to change UI language some other way.

**UPDATE**

I have version 1.5.0

[image]

which is the latest

[image]

from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble_(software)

**UPDATE 2**

I have downloaded it from here: http://files.kde.org/marble/downloads/windows/marble-setup-1.5.0.exe

Comment: This is handled by the application if the option is not there the. You don't have the version that supports doing what you want

Comment: Where to get one?

Comment: Get one of what?

Comment: @Ramhound What you wrote "You don't have the version that supports doing what you want"   <-- You wrote that. It was easily interpreted to have suggested that there was a version that supports what he wants

Comment: If you say so; the documentation isn't wrong though just verified on my Surface Pro 3

Comment: Oh. I just want to change UI language...

Comment: @Ramhound don't you see my screenshot?

Comment: @Dims  Where is the link that you downloaded it from?

Comment: That is handled entirely by the application so you must have a old version of Marble which does not match the documentation

Comment: @Dims I see a screenshot which i can't understand; I also understand your question just not your comment.

Comment: @Ramhound His screenshot shows the Help menu expanded and the option he needs not there

Comment: @Ramhound items there are saying, from top to bottom: (1) marble manual, (2) what is this, (3) about marble globe, (3) about qt

Comment: The one I installed marble-setup-1.5.0.exe, also doesn't have the option  http://i.imgur.com/Bp3F9js.png  How did you make yours in that language you used? What did you install?

Comment: But yours is English! Hence it CAN :)

Comment: @Dims yes it can. Can you answer, what did you install that made yours the language yours is?

Comment: I am in Russia and locale is Russian, but default Windows GUI language is English.

Comment: Probably program reacts on locale or something

Comment: @barlop I installed EXE I linked in the question, nothing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15671/discussion-between-barlop-and-dims).